# tables withour border, the lines goes down in the second line

Tags: html, border

I need help in this:

if i try to integrate this on a newsletter mailchimp the lines goes down here is the screenshot:

http://i197.photobucket.com/albums/aa253/tintingerri/Test/pic4.png

can someone help me why is this happening?
if I test this in a textpad it looks good, and if I try to put the code now in mailchimp, it the lines are reformatted. any idea?
thanks

Comment: thanks for migrating here. sorry for the wrong posting. can someone please tell me what's the code for a background of a particular cell? thanks

Comment: Apply border-color:#008000;border-style: solid none none none;border-width:2px;  for the td for which you want the top border.

Comment: thanks, but if I put the width: the 2nd column is moving to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
td { border-top:2px solid #fb0 }
td { padding-left:25px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:10px; width: 30% }
tr.alt { background: #ffc }
```

the row to have the background will use

```
<tr class="alt">
```

it is also common practice to put all the style in a css file or in the separate `<style>` tag region.

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/2LXUn/2/

Comment: thanks but when I put the width:30% the second column moved to the right. Don't know why...

Comment: where shall i add the one you write in the css style?

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
border-top: 1px solid #000;
```

To the `style` attribute for the `<td>` tags.

You can change the color to anything you want obviously and you may want to look into using external CSS stylesheets.

Comment: thanks how can I have this as 100% because when I tried this, the line is only too short. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want a table, with only border at the top, the following will work.

> <table style="**border-color:#008000;border-style: solid none none none;border-width:2px; width: 100%**">
>      <tr> <td >       row1</td>
>     </tr> <tr >
>         <td>row2</td>     </tr>
>   </table>

You may also apply the border style to table rows as required.

Comment: check this out here: the second column move to the right if I put the width: 100% : http://jsfiddle.net/2LXUn/6/